# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2-2x+2=0$ then the least value of n for which $\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^n=1$

Tags: quadratics

So simple thought here.

Shoudnt n simply be zero? I mean there is no condition that states n cannot 0, so why is the answer 4? It may be an obvious answer, but i can’t get my head over it.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose they are asking for the least **positive** integer $n$.  The roots are $ 1 \pm i$ so the proof that $4$ is the least positive integer is quite trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation has the solutions $1+i$ and $1-i$. Furthermore
$$\frac{1+i}{1-i} = i$$
Although $i^0 = 1$ i think they want $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 1$ what leads you to $n=4$ since 
$$i^1 = i \neq 1,$$
$$ i^2 = -1 \neq 1,$$
$$i^3 = -i \neq 1$$
$$i^4 =1$$

Comment: Only if you are a 'bad guy' and think $0\not\in\mathbb N$. One of Peano's axioms clearly states that $0\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: whoops, fixed it. Don't want to start a fight on whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ah, ah... Kidding! I am aware many people make start $\mathbb N$ from $1$...

Answer (score 4):

Let $\dfrac\alpha\beta=r$  we need $$r^n=1$$

$2=(1+r)\beta$

$2= r\beta^2$

$$\dfrac2r=\left(\dfrac2{1+r}\right)^2\iff r^2+2r+1=2r\iff r^2=-1$$

Comment: +1, for doing it without finding $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

$x_{1,2} =1\pm i$;

$x_{1,2}= √2e^{\pm i(π/4)}$;

1)$x_1/x_2=i$; 2) $x_2/x_1=-i$;

1)' $(x_1/x_2)^n=i^n=1$ $ \rightarrow$ $n=4,8,..$

2)' Can you finish?